# Bypassing session login redirect for index robots only using express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I've written a webapp on NodeJS Express/SailsJS, all my internal content pages are protected by an authentication session middleware using passportJS. So far so good.

Thing is, I want to be able to render the pages freely without redirecting to login only for certain user agents so pages are indexable but not renderable for a user browser.

How do I achieve that? I've explored building a custom middleware that transcends the authentication mechanism but haven't had any accomplishments yet.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the middleware with which you tried so far? Seems to be a good idea to me. Have a look at their middleware policies form their documentation: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/middleware